# How do i create a file in a sub directory in C++?

Tags: c++, ofstream

Here is my code, how do i create a file in the sub directory contacts? Every time the file is created, it appears in the same directory as my program.

```
int main(){
ofstream myfile("\\contacts");
myfile.open ("a");
myfile.close();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Specify the full path in the constructor:

```
ofstream myfile(".\\contacts\\a"); // or just "contacts/a"
if (myfile.is_open())
{
}
```

The posted code attempts to create a file called `"\\contacts"` and then another file called `"a"`.

Note:

- that `ofstream` will not create intermediate directories: `"contacts"` must exist prior to the use of the `ofstream`.
- the destructor will close the `ofstream` so it is unnecessary to explicitly call `myfile.close()`.

Comment: just a heads up - the solution given is a windows solution and not a linux solution, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23277681/created-file-in-subdirectory-but-cannot-open-file/23279191#23279191

Answer (score 0):

If you write the file path as "a" you are saving it in the same directory as the program. If you want it in the contacts directory (which will be in the the program's directory) you must write the path of the file. This directory will be /contacts/a, so your code should be:

```
    int main(){
        ofstream myfile("\\contacts\\a");
        myfile.close();
    }
```