# created file in subdirectory but cannot open file

Tags: c++, linux, ofstream

I followed the instructions given in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13935357/how-do-i-create-a-file-in-a-sub-directory-in-c) for creating a file in a sub-directory.

```
ofstream forceFile;
forceFile.open(".\\output_files\\error_log.csv", ios::out | ios::app);
forceFile << "stuff" << "\r\n";
forceFile.close();
```

But now I have files, with size, in the base directory that cannot be opened and are named

```
.\output_files\error_log.txt
```

if I double click the file, I am told the file cannot be found and told to try a different path. if I open with notepad++ I am asked if I want to create the file. The an empty file is created in .\output_files

The files are created by my university linux cluster in the university shared server space, then I am viewing the file through an AFS link on my windows laptop.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem with a network file share.

Comment: If you are using linux, why are using backslash `'\\'` instead of forward slash `'/'` as the directory separator?

Comment: any idea how to remove the files .\output_files\error_log.csv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are using backslashes, not slashes.

The path component delimiter on UNIXes is `/`, not `\`.

And because `/` is not particularly special in a C string, you do not need to escape it with a backslash. So: not `\\`, not `\/` and certainly not `//`.

Comment: it would have been nice if the linked thread had included this tidbit in their answer

Comment: Yes, it would. Except the contents of the path are not really within the scope of the C++ question.

Comment: also, is it "./output_files/error_log.csv" or ".//output_files//error_log.csv"

Comment: @forest.peterson: In the interests of helping you to think for yourself a little (:P) what do you think the double `/` would do?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I think you misunderstood my question?

Comment: @forest.peterson: I think you misunderstood my answer.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Ok, do you want to take another crack at it - I appreciate the time you've put into this. But as it is now, the next person that reads this thread, will not have an answer.

Comment: @forest.peterson: I don't see why not. And if you think so, why did you mark it as accepted?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit if you can clarify and expand on "So: not \\, not \/ and certainly not //" that would be great